# Toggle "this == true" when "other thing == true", elif "other thing == false"

Tags: python, rendering, shape-keys

I'd like to control toggle of the shapekey visibility with empty object.
I have an "Empty" object in "Shapekey_1" collection which is under "Shapekeys" collection. I want the Empty object visibility to control "Key 1" shapekey visibility by toggling mute.

Here's what I've tried,

```
import bpy
if bpy.data.collections["Smile_1_10"].hide_render == True
    return bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Key 1"].mute == True
else return bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Key 1"].mute == False
```

and the error return as

```
Python:   File "\Text", line 2
    if bpy.data.collections["Smile_1_10"].hide_render == True
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: expected ':'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggested, you have an issue with your syntax.
if and else require an ":" at the end like so:

```py
import bpy
if bpy.data.collections["Smile_1_10"].hide_render == True:
    bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Key 1"].mute = True
else:
    bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Key 1"].mute = False
```

I also removed your return statements because your code is not part of a function.

Comment: Additionally, if OP wants to set these properties to true or false then they would need to use "bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Key 1"].mute = True" not "...mute == True".

"==" tests for equality, not set a variable value.

Comment: Omg thank you, not knowing coding fundamentals sucks!